# Checking if file exists before exporting

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across a macro from a user on this site but noticed it doesn't rename the file if already exists. Can someone please help;

```
docNameField = "PID"

    ' Create document for each Mail Merge record (loop)
    For rec = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord To lastRecord

        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = rec

        ' Set document name for current record
        If Trim(docNameField) = "" Then
            strDocName = "document" & rec & ".docx"
        Else
           strDocName = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(docNameField).Value
       End If

        ' Execute Mail Merge action
        With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .Execute
        End With

        ' Save generated document and close it after saving
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=savePath & strDocName & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        ActiveDocument.Close False

        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
    Next rec
```

I have seen a few guidlines on how to do this using manual pointers to save file location but within this sameple "savepath" is already defined based on the directory the file is in.

I am thinking something like the following;

```
Do While .FileExists(strPath)

    i = i + 1

    OutputFileName:=savePath & strDocName & i, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        ActiveDocument.Close False
Loop
```

I am unsure how to proceed / whether this is correct and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Take a read through here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Comment: `Dir()` is what you need. Read about it [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dir-function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Hi I am struggling to work with the link provided

Comment: ub Test_File_Exist_With_Dir()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\book1.xlsm"

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "File exist"
    End If

End Sub

Comment: i am not sure how to use this with the macro above. I not only wish to check if a file exists within the directory but rename it accordingly. would i need a incremental pointer that adds onto the outputfilename if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a FileExists function:

```
Public Function FileExists(sFileName As String) As Boolean
  Dim obj_fso As Object

  Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  FileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(sFileName)

  Set obj_fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thank you apologies i am not sure how to implement this. could you please assist? Would i need a function when the export and all variables are together? I was wondering whether i could run the check and rename at the point the document is exported to pdf as at this point the save path is already defined and so is the reference to the doc name

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to check if a file exists. While `Scripting.FileSystemObject` works fine, it's extremely slow. `Dir()` is much quicker.

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal Filename As String) As Boolean
     FileExists = Len(Dir(Filename, vbDirectory)) > 0
End Function


If FileExists("Some path") then ...
```

Comment: apologies i still do not know how to intergrate this into the code above. I am looking for a way to rename the file with a unique id if exists, i am thinking the following

Comment: I was wondering whether the "strdocname" value determined can be passed into this function then compare this to the files within the "savepath" directory (not sure what vbdirectory is)

Comment: You have to loop as shown in your second example, each time adding the index number to the file name e.g. "File1", "File2, "File3" and checking if exists. if yes, continue the loop, if no save and exit the loop.